# Second, third, etc. horizontal bullets (LI) being pushed down

Tags: html, css

On this page I've been asked to look at (see link below), the second and third LI inside UL#columns are being pushed down.

Removing `clear:both` on line 61 of default.css fixes this issue. However, I'm unclear as to why. Any ideas ?

```
#columns {width: 960px; clear: both; margin-top: 90px;}
#columns li {width: 290px; float: left; display: inline-block; background-position: center top; background-repeat: no-repeat; text-align: center; margin-right: 40px; opacity: 0;}
#columns li:nth-child(3) {margin-right: 0;}
#columns li h3 {font-size: 22px; color #33343d; display: block; clear: both; margin-top: 50px;}
#columns li P {color: #78797d; font-size: 15px; margin-top: 10px;}

#columns li.heart {background-image: url('../img/icons/heart.gif');}
#columns li.phone {background-image: url('../img/icons/phone.gif');}
#columns li.wheel {background-image: url('../img/icons/wheel.gif');}
```

[image]

Comment: Light me up. I don's see any list items on page.

Comment: what version of browser you have and what browser you use? because i can't see any problem with your site.

Comment: @Morpheus I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Looks OK in Chrome 23 and Firefox 19 on Windows

Comment: Version 25.0.1364.152 m.

Comment: Remove `float:left` and add `vertical-align:top` on the `<li>`. I can't check as I'm on an old version of Chrome that doesn't exhibit the problem

Comment: Now on Version 25.0.1364.160 m. Issue does persist if untouched. Thank you for your suggestions :)

Comment: Don't use `clear:both`, better use a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) when playing with `floats`. I rather prefer the magic of `inline-block` but it'll come to the same result :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `float:left` and `display:inline-block`, remove `float:left` and it'll work just fine !

Instead of using `inline-block`, you could use `float:left` with a `clearfix` like [this one](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) !

To make IE work with `inline-block` add those lines :

```
*display : inline;
*zoom : 1;
```